# How to do cross-validation with createFolds() and index argument of trainControl()?

Tags: r, cross-validation, r-caret

I want to make multiple machine learning models and compare the results to choose the best model.

According to DataCamp, for fair comparison of multiple models, models must use the same training/test splits when making folds.
Thus, rather than just using the following code, it is advisable to use createFolds() to make custom indices to be used in making each model.

```r
trainControl(method="cv", number = 5, ...)
```

To compare the process of cross-validation, I tried below code first.

```r
> myGrid <- data.frame(mtry=2)
> 
> trc <- trainControl(method="cv", number = 5, verboseIter = TRUE)
> m <- train(cyl~., mtcars, trControl = trc, tuneGrid=myGrid)
+ Fold1: mtry=2 
- Fold1: mtry=2 
+ Fold2: mtry=2 
- Fold2: mtry=2 
+ Fold3: mtry=2 
- Fold3: mtry=2 
+ Fold4: mtry=2 
- Fold4: mtry=2 
+ Fold5: mtry=2 
- Fold5: mtry=2

> m
Random Forest 

32 samples
10 predictors

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (5 fold) 
Summary of sample sizes: 27, 25, 25, 25, 26
```

I tried the same cross-validation (k=5) with custom folds that I made.

```r
> myFolds <- createFolds(mtcars$cyl, k=5)
> trc_index <- trainControl(index=myFolds, verboseIter = TRUE)
> m_index <- train(cyl~., mtcars, trControl = trc_index, tuneGrid=myGrid)
+ Fold1: mtry=2 
- Fold1: mtry=2 
+ Fold2: mtry=2 
- Fold2: mtry=2 
+ Fold3: mtry=2 
- Fold3: mtry=2 
+ Fold4: mtry=2 
- Fold4: mtry=2 
+ Fold5: mtry=2 
- Fold5: mtry=2 

> m_index
Random Forest 

32 samples
10 predictors

No pre-processing
Resampling: Bootstrapped (5 reps) 
Summary of sample sizes: 6, 6, 6, 7, 7
```

The big differences are 'Resampling'(Cross-Validated vs. Bootstrapped) and 'Summary of sample sizes' (27 vs 6).

I think the printed resampling method could be wrong, because I did not explicitly input the resampling method as 'cv'.

But I think the different sample sizes tell me that, I'm not doing it correctly. The sample size for each iteration should be around 25.

I tried 'indexOut' instead of 'index', but it still shows small sample sizes.

I could not find any appropriate guide with this issue with googling.

I think the code used in the following URL is not different from the one I used.
https://lgatto.github.io/IntroMachineLearningWithR/supervised-learning.html#model-selection-1

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: What do you mean by this: **I want to apply multiple machine learning techniques on the same data.**?

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not fluent in English. => I want to make multiple machine learning models for solving one question and compare the results to choose the best model.

Comment: I wrote up something that does that. However, it is meant to work with returning predictions too. In essence, you train with the same data and choose any model type(s). You can find details [here](https://github.com/Nelson-Gon/manymodelr/tree/develop). The function in question is `multi_model_1`.